# What is the oldest known story from the Paleolithic or Mesolithic, if any are known?

Tags: folklore

What is the oldest story known to have been told by people living a Palaeolithic or Mesolithic way of life, in other words who have not used metals such as copper, bronze or iron and who do not engage in herding or farming? This would include for example aborigine people in Australia living the way they lived before the invasion and conquest.

Comment: A second stick man from the right shot an animal

Comment: This is a problematic question because we can only date things that have a physical embodiment, such as a text or carving in stone.  As much as I like the spirit of this question, I can't see how it is answerable in the current form.